# Escape backslash from terminal input

Tags: java, escaping, command-line-interface

My program takes arguments from the terminal with the last argument being a path to a csv file. My problem is that the backslashes are always removed by the time it gets in my main class.

How can I let a user enter a windows-type file path and have the backslashes be there when entering my main method?

i tried to see if the backslash is there as a character like so:

```java
for (int num = 0; num < args[2].length(); num ++) {
            char c = args[2].charAt(num);
            if (c == '\\') {
                System.out.println("backslash found");
            }
        }
```

but it is just not there.

I also tried it like this:

```java
System.out.println(args[2].replace("\\", "\\\\"));
```

first try did not print backslash found and the second try just printed the path excluding any backslashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backslashes are most likely being removed by the command shell already because they use that as escape character as well. Check the passed value, most likely the value after the backslash is missing as well.

You have to escape the backslash when calling the program, e.g. like this:

```
java -cp myjar com.example.MyApp "param 1" "param 2" "path\\to\\example\\file.txt"
```

Alternatively, pass the path with forward slashes. Java supports these on Windows-systems as well.

Comment: So it's not possible? maybe that's why i couldn't find anything online. The passed value is actually still there, just the backslashes are missing, not that it matters I suppose. Appreciate the answer and saving me some time. cheers!